# Import multiple flat files to multiple SQL Tables

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, flatfilesource, oledbdestination

Here's my folder setup.

[image: Folder Structure]

Here's the File setup

[image: File Structure]

The idea is to traverse through the folders & put FileA contents to Table FileA.dbo on the database ( also FileB,FileC etc). The FileName structure is same throughout all the folders.

I have this ssis package where I parse through the folders with a foreachloop-> dataflow.

[image: ssis1]
[image: ssis2]

I have checked that the algorithm I've formulated to get the filename is working

```
REVERSE(Substring(Reverse( @[User::FileName] ),5,LEN( @[User::FileName] ))) == "FileA"
```

It parses out the .txt extension. Below is the setup of the foreach loop I have.
[image: Foreach]

To start this whole package I've .txt files inside the folder & I make the foreach container loop subfolders.

[image: startingpoint]

Since, I'm not really a SSIS package developer, this is the best I could do with some research. The problem I'm running into is, **it seems to work partially.**

The snapshots are mockups of the scenario I have and in reality I have over 200 folders with 50 text files each designated to dump the contents to respective named tables.

*But the total number of rows I'm seeing after the package successfully executes is extremely low & can't be right.* Is there anyway to get a count/list of the number of folders it traversed. Also, am I doing something wrong ?

Ideally, I'd just like to not have to start with .txt files but just have the whole thing go to folders, get the filenames ( which I think I've a working code for) & just dump all the info to the OLEDB Destinations.

Any help, link to resources is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes this can be done using only one data flow task with dynamic source and destination. I will provided a detailed answer with screenshots, but you have to wait for a while, because it needs time

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hadi . I'll be waiting for it

Answer (score 1):

## Solution overview

You can achieving this using one DataFlow Task inside the foreach loop, but the trick is that you have to Read source flat file name and the Destination SQL Table name from variables

*Note: Flat files structure must be the same and SQL Tables must have the same structure*

---

## Detailed Solution

1. Right Click on the `Control Flow` window and click on `Variables`

[image]

2. Declare 2 SSIS variables:

   - `FlatFilename` : of type `String` and assign a default value a random file path *(i.e. `C:\MockFolder\FileA.txt`)*
   - 'SQLTablename`: of type`String` and assign to the following expression:

*This is assuming that all destination tables has the same schema `dbo`*

```
 "[dbo].[" + REPLACE(RIGHT( @[User::FlatFilename] , FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::FlatFilename]  ) , "\\", 1) - 1),".txt","") + "]"
```

[image]

[image]

3. Add a `Foreach Loop Container` and a `DataFlow Task` inside it, click on the `DataFlow Task` and on the properties Tab, Set the `Delay Validation` property to `True`

[image]

4. Double Click on the `Foreach Loop container` and select the main Directory , and the files filter `*.txt` also choose the `fully qualified` retrieve file name option

[image]

5. Go To variable mapping Tab and choose the `@[User::FlatFilename]` variable

[image]

6. Add 2 Connection manager

   - FlatFileConnection: a Flat File connection manager, and configure it by selecting randomly a `File` *(i.e. `C:\MockFolder\FileA.txt`)*
   - OLEDBConnection: an OLEDB connection manager, and configure it to your Destination SQL Server Database
7. In The `DataFlow Task`, add a `Flat File Source` and an `OLEDB Destination`, in the `OLEDB Destination` select `Table name from variable` option and select `@[User::SQLTablename]` as the variable name

[image]

8. Map columns between source and Destination
9. Click on the `FlatFileConnection` in the connection manager windows, press `F4` to show the properties Tab, click on Expressions

[image]

10. Select the `Connection String` property assign to it the following expression:

    ```
    @[user::FlatFilename]
    ```

[image]

Comment: I'm just about to design a package according to your answer. But does this thing traverse subfolders though ? Pardon my relatively weak grasp on ssis knowledge but I thought we need to traverse subfolders via the Foreach loop or does this take care of it ?

Comment: Yes just check the traverse subfolder option in the foreach loop container

Comment: @thestralFeather7 i will be waiting for your reply

Comment: Sir, It's taking into account the extension of the file in the eval statement. I'm getting [dbo].[fileA.txt], I should really be getting [dbo].[fileA]. Hence, I can't map the columns as it is telling me that it can't find the object in the database

Comment: @thestralFeather7 oh i will fixed it, it is related to the expression used in `SQLTablename` variable.

Comment: @thestralFeather7 i fixed it up, use the following expression `"[dbo].[" + REPLACE(RIGHT( @[User::FlatFilename] , FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::FlatFilename]  ) , "\\", 1) - 1),".txt","") + "]"`

Comment: ok so when I run the package it error-ed out ( warnings ) with maximumerrorcountreached. [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "OLE DB Destination" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

Comment: `VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA` is thrown when destination table structure are differents. In my answer i assumed that table structures should be the same. Else you cannot achieve this using SSIS. You may need to build dynamic SQL command

Comment: yep it's showing that some column needs to be removed from external columns. Now I'm not sure why that is because there are no discrepancies regarding the files

Comment: @thestralFeather7 you should use one structure for all tables

Comment: as in ? don't think I'm following you. As in all the tables should have the same number of columns or something ?

Comment: Yes the columns names and count should be the same.

Comment: yep I don't think that should be an issue though

Comment: @thestralFeather7 at the end, even if that couldn't solved your issue, i am happy that you have learned many things about ssis: *Variables, Expressions, Dynamic Sources, dynamic destinations, ...* so this will put you on the right way. And if you find this answer helpful you can upvote it or accept it. Best wishes

Comment: oh it has definitely helped dude. Thanks a ton. Will do. Still learning , thanks!

Comment: hello friend. If not the server part , is there a way I can all FileA (s) to one folder, all FileB (s) to another etc after traversing through all the folders

I made an updated question over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798748/how-to-traverse-multiple-folders-multiple-files-dump-data-to-sql-tables-with

Comment: In the foreach loop change `*.txt` to `FileA.txt`